# Magento2: last order disappeared

Tags: magento2, orders, backend

The last order disappeared from the Magento2 backend (sales->orders).
The invoice related to that order is still visible in the list of invoices but when I try to open it I get a 404 with the following error:

```
Invoice capturing error
```

Any idea what when wrong and how I can fix this ?

Comment: Have you check log files ?

Comment: I am not sure which log I should check ... I just checked the most recent logs in /var/log but I can't find anything relevant